# Programmatically get all accounts in android phone with delphi

Tags: android, delphi, accountmanager

How can I get all accounts in android phone with Embarcadero Delphi? I know that we use [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to get accounts in Java. But how is it in Delphi? Can anyone help me?

Comment: See this detailed answer to a similar SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39581114/2817399

Answer (score 3):

You can access any Java classes via the JNI bridge. There is a utility to build wrappers, or you can use a pre-generate one. Here is one for [API level 21](https://github.com/FMXExpress/android-object-pascal-wrapper/blob/5f21605bd45a1947f8de2cf37c2f2c5ee239197a/android-21/android.accounts.AccountManager.pas) or you can [browse more here](https://github.com/FMXExpress/android-object-pascal-wrapper). You can also generate your own with [Java2OP](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Java2OP.exe,_the_Native_Bridge_File_Generator_for_Android).